# Unable to get correct value on click of elements added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why doesn't the code below print it's corresponding value when clicked?

Instead, it prints 5?

```
var recipeDiv = document.createElement("div");
var recipeUL = document.createElement("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    var listNode = document.createElement("li");
    listNode.innerHTML = i;
    listNode.onclick = function() { alert(i); }
    recipeUL.appendChild(listNode);
}
recipeDiv.appendChild(recipeUL);
addNodeToDOM(document.body, recipeDiv, 'recipe');

function addNodeToDOM(element, node, id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = id;
    div.appendChild(node);
    element.appendChild(div);
}
```

I was able to reproduce the bug here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p58crsjc/)

But basically, I'm not sure if this is the convention for adding elements correctly to the DOM. If so, how come whenever I click on the list elements, it doesn't show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple solution is to have a wrapper function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    (function(i){

      var listNode = document.createElement("li");
      listNode.innerHTML = i;
      listNode.onclick = function() { alert(i); }
      recipeUL.appendChild(listNode);

    })(i);
}
```

This way you can always rely on the iterator variable `i`.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When, `onclick` handler executes, the value of `i` will always show `5` as the `for` loop ends at 5th iteration,

Use `this.innerHTML`,

```
listNode.onclick = function() { alert(this.innerHTML); }
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p58crsjc/1/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks. I understand now. What if I was parsing through a JSON file and assigning onclick() based off of an array position i? How would I do that?

Comment: Iterate through the JSON array using a loop, assign the values, rest of the code would be almost similar to above.

Comment: Thinking about it... would storing it into an array be the only option?

Comment: Array would be a better option. There are many tutorials/answers available which could guide you.

Answer (score 0):

This is where closure concept plays its role. Try modifying `listNode.onclick = function() { alert(i); }` line of code with this:

```
listNode.onclick = (function(index) { return function(){alert(index);} })(i);
```

I have updated your fiddle..
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p58crsjc/2/)